# Call to a member function escape_str() on bool in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter Framework to update the data in the database and getting the following glitch while using Codeigniter core database feature such as `$this->db->update()`. However, If I use the normal SQL query, it is working fine.

> Type: Error
>   Message: Call to a member function escape_str() on bool
>   Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\code\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php
>   Line Number: 393

My Model code:

```
public function updatePolicy($data, $pid)
    {
        $this->db->where("id",$pid);
        $res = $this->db->update('tablename', $data);
        if ($res)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

My $data Array:

```
Array
(
    [agent_id] => 659
    [finace_company] => 23
    [vehicle_type] => 4
    [policy_month] => 2019-12-18
    [policy_number] => 3005/189/00/B00
    [name] => TEST
    [reg_number] => HR24Ab8585
    [proposal] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment2] => 
    [payment_mode_agent] => online
    [od_premium] => 1577.00
    [comments] => 24
    [branch] => 6
    [smId] => 12
    [frenchise] => 15
    [rejectStatus] => 0
)
```

And when i change reg_number with policy_number then it updated successfully.

Comment: Please check policy_number and reg_number feilds datatype from database. 
Otherwise share your $data array which you pass for update so we can suggest you to use the escape_str() or any other function help to you.

Comment: the datatype is VARCHAR(250)  and $data array is : Array
(
    [agent_id] => 659
    [finace_company] => 23
    [vehicle_type] => 4
    [policy_month] => 2019-12-18
    [policy_number] => 3005/189/00/B00
    [name] => TEST
    [reg_number] => HR24Ab8585
    [proposal] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment2] => 
    [payment_mode_agent] => online
    [od_premium] => 1577.00
    [comments] => 24
    [branch] => 6
    [smId] => 12
    [frenchise] => 15
    [rejectStatus] => 0
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably means your database connection has failed or was never attempted in the first place.
Try to create an another database in application->config->database.php

```
$db['another'] = array(
    'dsn'  => '',
    'hostname' => 'host',
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'dbname',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

public function updatePolicy($data, $pid)
{
$this->legacy_db = $this->load->database('another', true);
$this->legacy_db->where("id",$pid);
$res = $this->legacy_db->update('tablename', $data);
if ($res)
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

Hope this will work for you.